# Delete every x file in a directory - Python

Tags: python, image, computer-vision

is there a way to delete all files in a directory but only keep every x files ?

I have a directory which contains images, for a scene taken with a frequency of 10 frames per second. I want to keep every 5th frame.
Example:
if the folder is containing images from 0-10
I want to keep the 5th and the 10th image, and delete the others

Comment: How are they named?

Comment: How about `rm *[12346789].jpg`?

Comment: thanks a lot Mark :)
I didn't try what you proposed, but I used already the below script and it is doing what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume that they are all in a `folder` and that it contains only those images (and nothing else) then this should work in one complicated line:

```
import os
[os.remove(os.path.join(folder, img)) for i, img in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(folder))) if i % 5 != 0]
```

That should work regardless of how they are named and will only keep every 5th file (change the number 5 if necessary). However, **be very careful** to give the correct folder and make sure that it doesn't contain anything you don't want deleted. If it does, filter the list first before deleting.

If you're uncomfortable with list comprehensions or with the code being so unreadable (which it kinda is) the longer version of the above is:

```
import os
image_list = sorted(os.listdir(folder))
for i, img in enumerate(image_list):
    if i % 5 != 0:
        img_path = os.path.join(folder,img)
        os.remove(img_path)
```

Also, as per your comments, I have added a `sorted` function to make sure the order is kept alphabetically when removing every 5th element

Comment: Thanks a lot,
I tried the first one you added (the list comprehension). It nearly did the same but with some mistakes, it didn't correctly deleted the requested files to be deleted

so I have the images named from 0 to 149, the output was: 0, 5, 6, 25, 31, 42, 50, 53, 67, 69, .... and some others with a total of 31 files. As you can notice, it didn't count every 5 files correctly

Comment: I would need to know more details about what the file structure is or what went wrong with the deletion for extra help with that

Comment: just a folder with 149 jpg images

Comment: as I told you in the previous comment, it didn't keep every 5th file, but I think I know the problem. I believe that it doesn't list the file names inside the directory in the ascending order where they are, just a random listing, and accordingly, the deletion is not correct

Comment: 31 files is exactly what you would expect from keeping every 5th file of 149 files, perhaps their names are not sorted correctly, so I edited a `sorted` into my answer

Comment: Now it works fine .. Thanks a lot for the support :)